# global variable (matrix) in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use a numpy matrix as a global variable. However, when I reference the function below in other scripts I only get "global_gABD = []" and "gABD = matrix([[1,6,6]])" in my variable table (see attached picture). My gABD is not saved as global variable.

```
def gABD():

   global gABD
   import numpy as np
   gABD = np.matrix((1,6,6))
gABD()
```

Is there a way to do this or can numpy.matrix not be used globally?

[image]

Comment: Your variable name is the same as your function... this seems like a bad idea

Comment: What is a "variable table"? You can use anything you like as a global variable, although it's usually bad practice to do so; but note that your variable would overwrite your function since they have the same name.

Comment: My python interpreter software (spyder) allows me to see variables that currently used. Similar to Matlab if you are familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use global variables for this. However it is not considered good practice. You might want to read [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) Note, your variable and function have the same name, this *will* cause problems.

```
def gABD():

   global mat
   import numpy as np
   mat = np.matrix((1,6,6))
gABD()
print (mat)
# [[1 6 6]]
```

A better approach is to *return* the variable from your function so that it can be use elsewhere in the code:

```
def gABD():

   import numpy as np
   return np.matrix((1,6,6))

my_matrix = gABD()
print (my_matrix)
# [[1 6 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = 25
b = 37
def foo():
    global a  # 'a' is in global namespace
    a = 10
    b = 0
foo()
# you should have now a = 10 and b= 37. If this simple example works, replace then a by your matrix.
```

Comment: Yeah, integers as global variables are fine (this works for me). But as soon as I replace the value with a matrix it will ignore the global declaration. Therefore "a" is 10 in your example but when I set "a" as a matrix it gives me 25.

Comment: Ok, now try  the example provided by Jacques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964254/python-updating-global-variables